# Create a new column containing the total amount of occurrences of a string in R

Tags: r

I would like to assign a value in a new column (i.e.: country_count) of the amount of times a specific string occurs (in total) in my data frame.

```
country = c("DE", "FR", "FR", "FR", "NL","DE")
data_frame =data.frame(country)
```

This would be the resulting data frame.

```
country = c("DE", "FR", "FR", "FR", "NL","DE")
country_count = c(2, 3, 3, 3, 1,2)
data_frame =data.frame(country,country_count)
```

I am aware that I can simply run `table(data_frame$country)` to get the same result, but I would like to have the values in an additional column because ultimately I want to assign a different value to the strings (in my case countries) below a certain threshold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
data_frame %>%
  add_count(country, name="country_count")
```

returns

```r
  country country_count
1      DE             2
2      FR             3
3      FR             3
4      FR             3
5      NL             1
6      DE             2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can subset the `table()` result with your vector of country codes, then cast it to a data frame.

```r
country = c("DE", "FR", "FR", "FR", "NL","DE")
as.data.frame(table(country)[country])

# Result
#  country Freq
#1      DE    2
#2      FR    3
#3      FR    3
#4      FR    3
#5      NL    1
#6      DE    2
```

Answer (score 2):

Fairly straightforward option:

```
dplyr::count(data_frame, country)
```

Returns:

```
  country n
1      DE 2
2      FR 3
3      NL 1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data_frame)[, country_count := .N, country]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
data_frame$country_count <- with(data_frame, ave(seq_along(country), country, FUN = length))
```